# Passing data controller to view getting undefined variable, in Laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel, undefined

I want to passing data from controller to view

```
$participantView = view('section.participant', ['data' => $result['data']])->render();
```

the $result['data'] is array data(not empty)

I do `foreach` in view, and got:

> undefined variable: data

I also do with compact and 'with', but also getting undefined variable

What is wrong in my code?

Comment: Try : `return view('section.participant', ['data' => $result['data']]);`

Comment: what do you want to do with the view? why render()? why not directly return the view like this:

    return view('section.participant')->with('data', $result['data']);

Comment: yes, i want to passing the data to view. then i will return $data. which is $data=['data_array'=>['view'=>$participantView]];

Answer (score 0):

You must return the view, Try this :

```
return view('section.participant', ['data' => $result['data']]);
```

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
 $data = $result['data'];
 return view('section.participant', compact('data'));
```

It will do work.

Comment: i will return $data, $data=['data_array' => ['view' => $participantView ]]; that will i return to ajax.

Answer (score 0):

I want to passing the data to view, then I will return `$data`. Which is:

```
$data=['data_array' => ['view' => $participantView ]];
```

in another function, the passing data was fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$participantView = view('section.participant')->with([
    'data' => $result['data']
])->render();
```

and in view you will have $data variable available.

Comment: It's still same, still getting undefined variable data. I don't understand what's wrong, because in other function that work

Comment: still same. or there is a wrong way from my code? i load js function from view, the js function is calling ajax to the controller, and then in the controller passing data to view. from the controller, that will return the view to ajax. is it wrong?

Comment: It seams that your problem is there. You are returning the view content, a string, rather then a view object. It's not going to work that way.

Comment: Maybe this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28634712/how-can-i-return-a-view-from-an-ajax-call-in-laravel-5

Comment: but, for some reason. in other function(which is using the same function like that) that work XD.