# Laravel 5 how to compose GET route to INDEX if my search query is also a GET to the INDEX?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5

I'm making an app, where I have a **users table** on the INDEX with a **search box** above, where you're able to perform **ajax** search. My problem is, that so far I could only do the ajax search on a **separate page**, because it's a GET request on the INDEX, as well as my **original** INDEX request, where the PHP shows all the entries. Therefore, if I direct my search onto the INDEX, the page reloads anyways because of the `\App\User::all();` PHP function.

My goal is to have **just a single page**, where I have my users table with all the entries, but when I perform some search, only the relevant entries get displayed in the table.

My current routes:

```html
Route::resource('index', 'UsersController');
Route::get('results', 'SearchesController@search');
```

My search function:

```html
public function search(Request $request) {
            
            $keyword = $request->get('keyword');

            if($keyword !== ''){
                $users = \App\User::where("username", "LIKE","%$keyword%")
                        ->orWhere("firstname", "LIKE", "%$keyword%")
                        ->orWhere("lastname", "LIKE", "%$keyword%")
                        ->orWhere("email", "LIKE", "%$keyword%")
                        ->orWhere("phone", "LIKE", "%$keyword%")->get();
                
                    return view('pages.results', array( 'users' => $users ));
                    
            } elseif(empty($users) || $keyword == "") {
                
                    return view('pages.results');
            }
        }
```

My current view (the same both on INDEX and RESULTS pages):

```html
@if(isset($users) && !$users->isEmpty())
        <tr>
          <th class='text-center'>Username</th>
          <th class='text-center'>Firstname</th>
          <th class='text-center'>Lastname</th>
          <th class='text-center'>Email</th>
          <th class='text-center'>Phone</th>
          <th class='text-center'></th>
        </tr>
        @foreach($users as $user)
        <tr>
          <td class='text-center'>{{$user->username}}</td>
          <td class='text-center'>{{$user->firstname}}</td>
          <td class='text-center'>{{$user->lastname}}</td>
          <td class='text-center'>{{$user->email}}</td>
          <td class='text-center'>{{$user->phone}}</td>
          <td class='text-center'>{!! link_to_action('UsersController@edit', 'Edit', $user->id, ['class'=>'btn btn-warning', 'style'=>'margin-bottom:5px']); !!}
                                    {!! Form::open(['action' => ['UsersController@destroy', $user->id], 'method' => 'DELETE']) !!}
                                        {!! Form::submit('Delete', ['class'=>'btn btn-danger']) !!}
                                    {!! Form::close() !!}</td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
    @else
    <td class="text-center"><b>No results found, please try again.</b><br /><a href="{{ url('index') }}"><b>Display All</b></a></td>
    @endif
```

My current JS:

```html
$('.searchbar').keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.which == 13) {
    
            $.ajax({
                dataType: "json",
                url: '/results',
                data: {keyword: $('.searchbar').value()},
                success: function (result) {
                        console.log($user.name);
                },
                error: function(){
                        console.log("No results.");
                }
            });
            
        }
    });
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't see any reason to use ajax if all you want to do is filter results on your index page. This can be done with javascript. [example here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9127498/how-to-perform-a-real-time-search-and-filter-on-a-html-table)

Comment: As for your code: you are returning whole view in your controller instead of data that you could use in your javascript. You should check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28634712/how-can-i-return-a-view-from-an-ajax-call-in-laravel-5)

Comment: Thanks man for the clever answers, they're really useful!

Comment: Post it as your answer, so I can accept it for you! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any reason to use ajax if all you want to do is filter results on your index page. This can be done with javascript ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9127498/how-to-perform-a-real-time-search-and-filter-on-a-html-table))

As for your code: you are returning whole view in your controller instead of data that you could use in your javascript. You should check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28634712/how-can-i-return-a-view-from-an-ajax-call-in-laravel-5). After that just replace your data in html with data returned from ajax.