# Laravel passing data from ajax to modal view which is on a separate file causing modal to not render

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

Here is my blade view, it lists debiturs and all their properties like id, name, address. This also have a modal view button that pops a modal that is supposed to query the debitur by id then show the details of it `data-target="#viewModal" onclick='showDetail({{$var->id}});`

(ajax_table.blade):

```
<?php
if(!empty($data)){$isi = json_decode($data);}
if(!empty($modaldata)){$isimodal = json_decode($modaldata);}
 ?>

@if(!empty($isi->data))
    @foreach($isi->data as $var)
    @include('userdebitur.ajax_modal_view')
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $var->id }}</td>
        <td>{{ $var->name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $var->address }}</td>
        @endif
        <td>
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button title="Detail Info" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-flat" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#viewModal" onclick='showDetail({{$var->id}});'><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></button>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
@else
    <tr><td align="center" colspan="5">Not found.</td></tr>
@endif
```

Here is my modal file that is called from above (ajax_modal_view.blade):

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="viewModal">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content mdl-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Default Modal</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>test @if(isset($isimodal)){var_dump($isimodal)} @endif</p> //I'm trying to output this
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The modal view button also called showDetail() passing debitur id as variable then returning data from the controller by calling a function inside ajax.blade:

```
function showDetail(id)
{
    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url: "{{ url('ajax/userdebitur/') }}"+"/"+id,
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        success: function(modaldata){        
            $("#viewModal").html(modaldata.view); //this is likely the problem
        },
        error: function (modaldata) {
            // 
        }
    });
}
```

And this is my controller:

```
public function getdebitur($id)
{
    $content = Debitur::find($id);
    $modaldata['content'] = $content;
    $modaldata['view'] = view('userdebitur.ajax_modal_view')->with('modaldata', json_encode($content))->render();

    echo json_encode($modaldata);
}
```

When using console in web browser, I have successfully retrieved the selected debitur data showing all the objects, however I can't seem to pass anything to the modal.
I have tried passing the data to the ajax_table.blade itself, moving the modal inside ajax_table.blade, passing data without view from the controller, moving json_decode($modaldata) inside the modal itself, all to no avail.

If in the ajax.blade I use `$("#viewModal").html(modaldata.view);` modal is showing for one second then disappear, but if I use `$("#viewModal").modal(modaldata.view);` or `$("#viewModal").modal(modaldata);` it's showing with no $isimodal value.

What I want to do: getting the value passed from the controller and var_dump it in the modal.

Comment: Maybe try `$("#viewModal").append` instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I return a view from an ajax call in Laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28634712/how-can-i-return-a-view-from-an-ajax-call-in-laravel-5)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. The error was caused by the modal being updated by the ajax inside another modal, instead of replacing the whole modal.

The solution is to remove `<div class="modal fade" id="viewModal">` from my modal file, and then it will render properly.